# How to Populate primefaces data table after searching database

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am developing an application and I want to edit my data table row wise. The problem I am facing is that if I populate my `ArrayList` in `getter` method that `rowEdit` action don't works, but when I populate list in `@PostConstruct` method with `@ViewScoped` than `rowEdit` works. So, now I have a field to search values from database and display in data table. I can't able to populate values in data table on creating `managedbean` because in order to search I have to send field value to search method but in `@postConstruct` I can't. PLease help me out.

Here is my code Snippet:

```
<p:dataTable id="patients" rendered="#{viewBills.visible}"
                editable="true" value="#{viewBills.getPatientBills}" var="patient"
                style="margin-bottom:20px">

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" Listener="#{viewBills.updateEdited}" update="@form"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" Listener="#{viewBills.onRowCancel}" update="@form"/>

                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.patName}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{patient.patName}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>

                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Department">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.department}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.department}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Amount">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.amount}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.amount}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Implant">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.implant}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.implant}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Ceramic Lab">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.ceramicLab}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.ceramicLab}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Comments">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.comments}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.comments}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Practical Charges">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.practicalCharges}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.practicalCharges}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Material Charges">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.materialCharges}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.materialCharges}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Fixed Ortho">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.fixedOrtho}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.fixedOrtho}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="MF Kit">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.mfKit}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.mfKit}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Army No">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.armyNo}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.armyNo}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Unit">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.unit}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.unit}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Armed Forces">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{patient.armedForces}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{patient.armedForces}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:50px">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

And here is my managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "viewBills")
@ViewScoped
public class ManageViewBIllsBean {

    public String mrNo;

    public boolean visible = false;

    public ArrayList<Patient> getPatientBills = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Patient> getAllPatientBills = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Patient> search() {
        getPatientBills = DatabaseHandler.searchBillByMrNo(mrNo);
        if (!getPatientBills.isEmpty()) {
            setVisible(true);
            return getPatientBills;
        } else {
            setVisible(false);
            return getPatientBills;
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        getGetPatientBills();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public ArrayList<Patient> searchAllBills() {
        return DatabaseHandler.searchAllBills();
    }

    public void executeViewAllBills() throws IOException {

        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/viewAllBills.xhtml");

    }

    public void executeViewBillsByMRNo() throws IOException {

        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/viewBillsByMRNo.xhtml");

    }

    public void updateEdited(RowEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println(" i am in edit");
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Car Edited", ((Patient) event.getObject()).getPatName());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edit Cancelled", ((Patient) event.getObject()).getPatName());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public String getMrNo() {
        return mrNo;
    }

    public void setMrNo(String mrNo) {
        this.mrNo = mrNo;
    }

    public ArrayList<Patient> getGetPatientBills() {
        return getPatientBills;
    }

    public ArrayList<Patient> getGetAllPatientBills() {
        return getAllPatientBills;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just like you would when using a fixed array and not using searching or a database. PrimeFaces has **no knowledge** on how you get your data.

Comment: I can do that but the problem is I have argument "MR NO" which will be set as WHERE clause in SQL query and that MR number will be entered by user so on creating bean i can't do that

Comment: Then your problem is totally unclear for me, sorry. Do you have a problem searching? From the datatable or not? Please try to make your problem clear. The **RIGHT** answer to the question as it stands is what is in my first comment. Or do you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559089/lazy-loading-in-datatable-jsf

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have understood.
You have an input for your MR NO (a number). And when the user submits that input, you want your datatable to be populated by the data you got from your SQL query.

What you should do is use a `<p:commandButton>` to submit your MRNO. It should call a method that runs your query, and update your `<p:dataTable>` like so :

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit MR NO" 
                 action="#{viewBills.loadPatientsFromDatabase}" 
                 update="patients" />
```

And so, you need a proper method in your bean :

```
public void loadPatientsFromDatabase()
{
    getPatientBills = DatabaseHandler.searchBillByMrNo(mrNo);
    setVisible = getPatientBills.isEmpty() ? false : true;
}
```

That should do the trick to get your dataTable to get its data.

However, there seems to be many things going on in your code that should be improved, such as naming. And calling the `getGetPatientBills()` in your `init()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hi, so effectively you agree with my first comment on the question. The same as with a non-database related array on which you do a filter, split or whatever.

Comment: Indeed, no matter how the data is obtained, any update on the dataTable would fill it with the current data.